# determine $\iiint zdv$ using spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates

Let $D$ be the region enclosed by the surface $z = \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$ and $z = -\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Determine:

$$\iiint zdv$$

using Spherical coordinates.

I'm trying to solve the above but I'm unsure how to go about it.

My attempt has been:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2}\int_{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} zdv$$

which I then integrate the first layer leaving me with:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2} 2-x^2-y^2dv$$

Should I have subbed in the spherical coordinates right at the start and integrated it as:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2}\int_{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}p\cos\phi p^2\sin\phi dp d\theta d\phi$$

Based on a users input, would I have to first rewrite $z = \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$ and $z = -\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

In terms of spherical coordinates?

Comment: That second form is simply non-sense!  "x" and "y" have no meaning in spherical coordinates.

Comment: So I would have to rewrite the bounding functions in terms of spherical coordinates?

Comment: Now that I look at it your first form doesn't make sense either!  What is "dv"?  Why do you still have "dv" after the first integration?

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction. I'm not familiar with spherical coordinates

Comment: @DamianJacobs [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates) is an introduction to them.

Comment: @DamianJacobs: If you're not familiar with spherical coordinates, then you're not ready to tackle this problem yet, to be honest. You have to a least learn the basics first.

Answer (score 1):

The given region is that from a cone up to the sphere "capping" the cone.  $\rho$ goes from 0 to 2 (the radius of the sphere) and $\theta$ goes from 0 to $2\pi$ (the complete circle).  $\phi$ goes from 0 (vertical) down to the cone, $\pi/4$. Since $z=\rho cos(\phi)$ in spherical coordinates, the integral is
$\int_0^2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/4} \rho cos(\phi) (\rho^2 sin(\phi)d\phi d\theta d\rho)$$= \int_0^2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/4}\rho^3sin(\phi)cos(\phi)d\phi d\theta d\rho$.

That can easily be done as
$\left(\int_0^2\rho^3d\rho\right)\left(\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta\right)\left(\int_0^{\pi/4} sin(\phi)cos(\phi) d\phi\right)$

Comment: How did you determine $\frac{\pi}{4}$?

Comment: I believe your range for $\phi$ is wrong. Namely, the correct integral is $$\int_{x=-2}^2\int_{y=-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} z\,dz\,dy\,dx = 0$$
but your integral is not zero.

Comment: @user247327 Thank you very much I went over your answer and did some research. Found a nice video explaining what each set of bounding values represent and that along with your answer has cleared it up for me.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBcNOkwiS6k

Answer (score 0):

Combine $z = \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$ and $z = -\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ to get $z=-\sqrt2$, which corresponds to the boundary $\cos\theta = \frac zr =-\frac{\sqrt2}2$, or $\theta =\frac{3\pi}4$, in spherical coordinates.

Then, the integral is
$$\int_V zdv = 2\pi \int_{\frac{3\pi}4}^\pi\int_0^{2}(r\cos\theta )\>r^2\sin\theta drd\theta=- 2\pi
$$